# Enable automatic zoom with SKZoonLevelConfiguration

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps

Here is the situation, I want to set up the navigation mode to adjust the zoom to route according to the current speed. See my code:

```
SKZoomLevelConfiguration[] zoomConfgs = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration[4];
zoomConfgs[0] = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(0.0f, 10.0f, 15.0f);
zoomConfgs[1] = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(10.0f, 20.0f, 13.0f);
zoomConfgs[2] = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(20.0f, 60.0f, 10.0f);
zoomConfgs[3] = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(60.0f, 100.0f, 8.0f);

SKNavigationSettings navSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
navSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.REAL); 
navSettings.setNavigationMode(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationMode.CAR); 
navSettings.setDistanceUnit(SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER_METERS);
navSettings.setZoomLevelConfigurations(zoomConfgs);
navSettings.setPositionerVerticalAlignment(-0.25f);

SKNavigationManager.getInstance().setNavigationListener(navListener);
SKNavigationManager.getInstance().setMapView(surfaceView);
surfaceView.getMapSettings().setMapDisplayMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_3D);
SKNavigationManager.getInstance().startNavigation(navSettings);
isNavigating = true;
```

So the fact here is the map isn't zooming when the navigation is activated. Probably i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.5 there was an issue with this API - it was fixed for 2.6.

Here is a code snippet of how it works in 2.6:

```
    /** 
     * Launches a navigation on the current route 
     */ 
    private void launchNavigation() { 
        if (TrackElementsActivity.selectedTrackElement != null) { 
            mapView.clearTrackElement(TrackElementsActivity.selectedTrackElement); 

        } 
        // get navigation settings object 
        SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings(); 
        // set the desired navigation settings 
        navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationType.SIMULATION); 
        navigationSettings.setPositionerVerticalAlignment(-0.25f); 
        navigationSettings.setShowRealGPSPositions(false); 

        SKZoomLevelConfiguration[] configurations = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration[2]; 
        configurations[0] = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(0, 70, 10); 
        configurations[1] = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(70, 100, 15); 
        navigationSettings.setZoomLevelConfigurations(configurations); 
        // get the navigation manager object 
        SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance(); 
        navigationManager.setMapView(mapView); 
        // set listener for navigation events 
        navigationManager.setNavigationListener(this); 

        // start navigating using the settings 
        navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings); 
        navigationInProgress = true; 
    }
```

**Note:** The speed values(km/h) set in SKZoomLevelConfigurations are correlated to the current speed(m/s) from SKNavigationState. 
The `onUpdateNavigationState(SKNavigationState navigationState)` method provides notifications when data related to the current speed is updated.

Comment: So, it means in 2.6 i should set the SKZoomLevelConfiguration on meters per seconds instead kilometers per hour?

Comment: When is the next sdk release  is scheduled to be out?